# R does not assign numbers to dates in the right order

Tags: r

I am working on a document were I have a list of tests with dates.
I am trying to get R to pivot them horizontally, with the first test showing up first and the later tests showing up later.
However, when applying functions such as sort() or order() or even group_by(), R still sometimes shows an earlier test in the first column pivotted to horizontal.

I would think I should apply some sort of odering to the date column before numbering, so that R numbers the actual first test with the first numerical value with which I am pivotting.

Any idea as to how I would go about this?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
employee nr.  date          date2        test_1   test_2  
x             2010/01/10    2010/01/05   positive positive 

.................................
```

It should be so that the 2 dates are switched. The date is formatted as yyyy/mm/dd.
In the original dataset it was formatted as dd/mm/yy (you can see the format change in the code).

My expected output should look something like this:

employee nr.  date          date2        test_1   test_2
x             2010/01/05    2010/01/10   positive positive

```
#specify dates as variable "date" for R to recognize the variable

ct_clean$date <- as.Date(ct_clean$date, origin = "1899-30-12", format = "%d/%m/%y") 

###assign number to duplicate value of employee number (if multiple tests -> multiple entries)

ct_numbered <- ct_clean %>% group_by(employee) %>% mutate(test_nr = row_number())
ct_clean %>% group_by(employee) %>% mutate(test_nr = 1:n())
ct_clean %>% group_by(employee) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_len(n()))
ct_clean %>% group_by(employee) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_along(employee))              

#spread out multiple test for one individual horizontally

ct_wide <- ct_numbered %>% group_by(date) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "test_nr", 
     values_from = "ct",
     names_expand = TRUE, names_vary = "slowest")   

 #merging rows to include the test-data and test-number in the same row 

 ct_df <- ct_wide %>%
 group_by(employee) %>%                                                         
 mutate(id = seq_along(employee)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = date, names_prefix = "date") %>%  
 summarize_all(list(~ .[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

Comment: Could make your expected output more clear?

Comment: @shs I have tried to make it more clear, please let me know if it is still not quite clear enough.

Comment: so do just want to switch the columns? Or is sometimes the earlier one first and sometimes second and you want to switch them only in cases when the earlier one is second? Your data sample of one row doesn't really give much to understand the structure of your problem

Comment: I want the columns to switch when the first date showed is not the chronologically first date (this is sometimes the case and sometimes not) the example I give is a case were the collumns are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `if_else()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(employee = c("x", "y", "z"), date1 = structure(c(14619, 
14611, 14619), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(14614, 14614, 
14614), class = "Date"), test_1 = c("positive", "negative", "negative"
), test_2 = c("positive", "positive", "positive")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(employee = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), date1 = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), date2 = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), test_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), test_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
d
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   employee date1      date2      test_1   test_2  
#>   <chr>    <date>     <date>     <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 x        2010-01-10 2010-01-05 positive positive
#> 2 y        2010-01-02 2010-01-05 negative positive
#> 3 z        2010-01-10 2010-01-05 negative positive
```

```r
d |> 
  mutate(date1 = if_else(d$date1 < d$date2, d$date1, d$date2),
         date2 = if_else(d$date1 < d$date2, d$date2, d$date1), 
         test_1 = if_else(d$date1 < d$date2, d$test_1, d$test_2),
         test_2 = if_else(d$date1 < d$date2, d$test_2, d$test_1)
         )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   employee date1      date2      test_1   test_2  
#>   <chr>    <date>     <date>     <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 x        2010-01-05 2010-01-10 positive positive
#> 2 y        2010-01-02 2010-01-05 negative positive
#> 3 z        2010-01-05 2010-01-10 positive negative
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to order the dates before assigning numbers to duplicate values. (ct_numbered)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem:

The argument had to be passed in the code for assigning numbers to the duplicates.

The original code looked like this:

```
ct_numbered <- ct_variant  %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = 
row_number())
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = 1:n())
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_len(n()))
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_along(umcg))
```

This is the solution I used:

```
ct_numbered <- ct_variant %>% arrange(ymd(ct_variant$date)) %>% group_by(date, 
umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = row_number())
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = 1:n())
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_len(n()))
ct_variant %>% group_by(date, umcg) %>% mutate(test_nr = seq_along(umcg))
```